# css - slide right menu in responsive design

Tags: html, css

Please find this jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrWfy/) . When the screen size is less than 600px, the top menu bar is converted into responsive menu. When user hovers on "Menu" text (this text is used only for the demo), the menu appears. This works well on desktop and smartphones. Now I tried to implement slide right transition when user clicks on "Menu" text. I modified below css class

```
.nav ul:hover li{
        display: block;     
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;      
    }
```

and add `transition` property. But it didn't work.

**How do I make slide right responsive menu from css ???**

Comment: tried with both `left` and `right` with `transition`. but still it doesn't work.

Comment: could you please show me in my jsfiddle ???-@maremp

Comment: What do you want : open the menu on click or open it on hover with a slide-in animation ?

Comment: Open menu with sliding effect on hover-@enguerranws

Comment: I would like to implement slide left menu as shown in this [example](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/). I tried to animate `<ul>` and `<nav>` but it didn't work.-@enguerranws

Answer (score 1):

This is not how i'd do it. You've to consider altering your HTML and CSS.

*for example, the word `menu` is simply written in HTML, which is semantically incorrect and becomes a blocker while trying to animate the element, because you've to keep the text visible and deal with the rest of `<li>`, meaning this prevents you from being able to easily animate the `<ul>` altogether upon hovering menu. IMHO Menu should be a separate element.*

However, to help you out with your current HTML and css, you can try something like this

```
.nav ul {
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../images/icon-menu.png) no-repeat 10px 11px;
    width: 74px;
    background-color: #5B9BD5;
    z-index: 1000;
    height:0px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s;
}
.nav li {
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-100%);
    /* hide all <li> items*/
    transform:translate(-100%);
    margin: 0;
    width:75px;
}
.nav ul:hover {
    height:auto;
}
.nav ul:hover li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0%);
    transform:translate(0%);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrWfy/12/)

*side note: above works in webkit browsers and latest browsers that doesn't require prefix for css3 transitions. remember to specify other browser prefixes to make it work cross browser*

Comment: works fine. Word menu is just for demo. Actual UI has an image. But how can I make to left push menu like in this [example](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/) ???- @T J

Comment: For that instead of animating each `<li>` we have to animate the `<ul>` or `<nav>` all together, for doing that we need something outside the structure being animated to trigger the animation (*like the menu button*).. which is why i mentioned that you've to change the HTML structure :)

Comment: I tried to animate `<ul>` and `<nav>` but didn't work. Could you please show me in your jsfiddle ???- @T J